# Get Interface Properties through reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, interface

I am using widely using `foovar.GetType().GetProperty("PropertyName").GetValue(foovar)` to get the property value of a variable variable through reflection. But it doesn't appears to work on interface types.

```
IFoo foo = GetFoo();
string fooName= foo.Name; //It works perfectly
```

I am working with a third party assembly so I don't have access to the implementation. There is a 'Name' property, and I can get the value. But can't through reflection.

When I try `string s = (string)foo.GetType().GetProperty("Name").GetValue(foo);` i get a null error: there is no 'Name' property

I have checked `PropertyInfo[] pi = foo.GetType().GetProperties();` and I can see about 200 properties, none of these is "Name". In fact many other 'intellisense properties' doesen't show up.

¿How can I retrive the value of a property of an interface type?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need Reflection for this? Have you tried to look at the imlementation with ILSpy, dotPeek or Reflector?

Comment: I have type wich properties I need to access in runtime. It has a LOT of them, of different types. I get the properties names and property types I need to use every time through a database or XML, and then use reflection and generics to get the vaules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The returned object may implement `IFoo` explicitly, so the `Name` property will be private.
You can use the interface type instead:

```
object property = typeof(IFoo).GetProperty("Name").GetValue(foo);
```

EDIT: If that doesn't work, then I can only assume the property is actually defined on some other interface which `IFoo` implements e.g.

```
public interface IBase
{
    string Name { get; }
}

public interface IFoo : IBase
{
}
```

In this case you'll need to find the actual interface which declares `Name` and use that.

Comment: Sorry, It keeps giving me the error. In fact, when I try 'typeof(IFoo).GetProperties()' I am having the same properties than when I try 'foo.GetType().Getproperties()'

Comment: Thanks! Followig your idea, at the editor, thorugh 'intellisense', I see the propery in IFoo is defined as 'string IBase.Name'. So the solution is'string s = (string)typeof(IBase).GetProperty("Name").GetValue(foo);' even if 'foo' is defined as IFoo. :)  By the way, you know any way to query an interface about its underliying implementation so I could got this (Name is in fact IBase.Name) through code?